# Creating a record not found through default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider the model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :queued, lambda { where(queued: true) }
  scope :unqueued, lambda { where(queued: false) }

  default_scope unqueued
end
```

Product.first yields the SQL query

> SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."queued" = 'f'
>   LIMIT 1

Now what if I want to create a record that is not "true to the default scope?" Like so:

```
Product.queued.create!
```

The product is in fact created, but ActiveRecord yields an error since it tries to find the product by it's id AND the default scope:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
  Couldn't find Product with id=15 [WHERE "products"."queued" = 'f']
```

Is there a workaround for this? I need to make sure that the product I create is queued. A simple workaround would be

```
p = Product.create
p.update_column(:queued, true)
```

It seems like the wrong answer to another problem though, or perhaps it is the right answer. Are there alternatives?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to not use `default_scope`. `default_scope` should only be used when you *always* need to apply the scope when searching for records. So, if you ever need to find a record where `queued` is true, then you should not be using `default_scope`.

One other way to get past default_scope is to use the [unscoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped) method, i.e.:

```
Product.unscoped.queued
```

But, in general, if you need to use ActiveRecord to find queued Products, I would recommend removing your `default_scope`.

Comment: yeah..`default_scope` is really little too much magic. Using a scope `queued`, and calling the scope when needed is better, though it is a bit more work, it is more clear.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This was my conclusion as well! Thanks.